# Working with DynamoDB and denormalizing in an attempt to convert from relational data to NoSql mindset

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

**When working with DynamoDB and denormalizing in an attempt to convert from relational data to NoSql mindset**

*I would like to understand the approach of  denormalizing in a particular curcomstance. Once this makes sense to me, I am pretty sure the knowledge floodgate will open.*

Let's assume I have a database (RDMS) for songs and I have genres.
I would probably do something like this

generas

```
|generaId | generaTitle|
|5| Rock & Roll|
|6| Hip Hop|
```

songs

```
titleid| generaId | title
321|5| Great Balls of Fire
322|6| Gimme Some More
```

I would join these tables to get the generaTitle, and I could easily update the genera title by simply updating one record

`UPDATE generas set generaTitle = 'Rock n Roll' where generaId = 5;`

In DynamoDB

```
titleid  '65as56ldjalskd23131sdad'
title: Great Balls of Fire
genre: Rock & Roll
```

So, lets assume I now have 100,000 song titles that are in Rock & Roll. Would I not have to perform a massive 100,000  record update to just change this?

-OR-

Is it normal to have some programmatic relationship so I could do this

```
titleid  '65as56ldjalskd23131sdad'
title: Great Balls of Fire
genre: 5
```

At application level I know that 5 = Rock & Roll from a prior query and have this cached.

I can wrap my head around secondary indexes and Global Secondary indexes from a query perspective.

It seem that there still needs to be some level of relationship.  I can  accept having 'Rock & Roll' 100,000 times over and over, but I can not accept the concept of updating 100,000 records to change Rock & Roll to Rock N Roll

It is as if every talk and publication talks around this and I think it is perhaps one of the biggest issues for us RDMS guys. Maybe It's just me.

Now if someone said to me, "you do not have database level relationships in NoSQL, but it is very normal if not assumed you would have tables you use for application level relationships" my entire world would change.

If that is not the case, can someone make this clear to me.

Comment: How often will you be changing "Rock & Roll to Rock N Roll"?

Comment: nosql is no magic, **you store everything what you are going to need so that your gets are fast** but if in your model you are doing too frequent puts, you may need to take different approach like storing too frequently changing things separately, But if you endup doing it to another extreme it becomes a sql like operation but the downside would be that your db won't support these join natively and your application will have to take the overhead.

Comment: @JsFlipper have you watched this yet? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k